# Integration appeared in expression of 2-point function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, correlation-functions

I have a question on Matthew D. Schwartz p.81, (7.14)

First, let's see the next image.

[image]

In the page, for efficiency, the author writes $\delta_{xi} = \delta(x-x_{i})$ and  $D_{ij} = D_{ji} = D_{F}(x_{i}, x_{j}) $ be the Feynman Prpagator $D_{F}(x_{1}, x_{2}) = \int {d^{4}k \over (2\pi)^{4}}{i \over k^{2}-m^{2}+i\epsilon}  \ e^{ik(x_{1}-x_{2})} $.
And he set that $m=0$ for simplicity and $\hbar =1 $.

So the Green's function equation for the Feynmann propagator can be written
$$\square_{x}D_{x1} = -i\delta_{x1},$$

where $\square_{x}$ is the d'Alembertian operator acting on the x coordinates.

Then, he argues that the 2-point function can be written as
$$ \langle\phi_{1}\phi_{2}\rangle = \int{d^{4}}x \ \delta_{x1}\langle\phi_{x}\phi_{2}\rangle = i\int{d^{4}}x \ (\square_{x}D_{x1})\langle\phi_{x}\phi_{2}\rangle \overset{(\star)} = i\int{d^{4}}xD_{x1}\square_{x}\langle\phi_{x}\phi_{2}\rangle .$$

But I can't understand the step $(\star)$ until now. The author explains that "where we have integrated by parts in the last step" but how integration by parts apply to deduce $(\star)$? How can we perform integration involving d'Alembertian operator?

Comment: You have to do by parts for each differential $\partial_{\mu}$ in d'Alembertian $\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}$ separately, and you  will eventually end up with two surface integrals (which goes to zero) plus the RHS of the integral

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. Uhm.. Perhaps.. Can you explain more detail?

Comment: you can write, for instance: $(\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu} A)B=\partial_{\mu}(B\partial^{\mu}A)-\partial_{\mu}A\partial^{\mu}B$. The first term in the RHS is essentially of the form of total divergence, so it goes to zero. Repeat the same process for the second term...